# Let $p$ be an integer such that $p > 1$. Prove that if $\forall$ $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p \mid mn$, then $p \mid m$ or $n$ then $p$ is prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is the question:

> Let $p$ be an integer such that $p > 1$. Prove that if $\forall$ $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p \mid mn$, then $p \mid m$ or $n$ then $p$ is prime.

I feel like this is not true since $4 \mid (68 = 4 \cdot 17)$, and $4 \mid 4$ but 4 is not prime?

Comment: If you want multiplication, use \cdot so it's not a decimal point. At any rate, I don't understand what $4\mid 68$ and $4\mid 4$ has to do with what you're trying to prove. It's not true that $4\mid mn\Rightarrow 4\mid m$ or $4\mid n$ for all $m,n$, so $4$ is not prime.

Comment: @ZoZO But $ 4 \;|\; 6 \cdot 10 = 60$ and $4 \not |\; 6, 4 \not |\;10$.

Comment: But $4$ doesn't divide $17$ ;)

Comment: @Scientifica: 4 divides 4 is enough; it said "or" not "and"

Comment: :o my bad you're right :)

Comment: It has to be true for *ALL* such m,n not just one.  4|4*17 and 4|4 but 68 = 2*24 and 4 doesn't divide 2 nor 17.

Comment: This is basically the converse of [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma).

Comment: This doesn't actually state that for prime p the statement will be true.  This merely states that the statement is only true for primes.

Answer (score 3):

The statement is that if "*for all* $m,n$ such that $p \mid mn$, either $p \mid m$ or $p \mid n$", then "$p$ is prime". Your example is a specific $m = 4$ and $n = 17$ such that $4 \mid 4 \cdot 17$ and $4 \mid 4$. This isn't a counterexample, and suggests you may be understanding the question wrong. I added the quotation marks in case it helps you parse what it's trying to say.

To prove it, suppose that $p$ were not prime, so that $p = ab$ and $a, b > 1$.
Then take $m = a$, $n = b$. What do you get?

Comment: Ah, I see now. I'm beating myself with a stick now

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $p$ isn't prime. Thus $p=ab$ where $a,b>1$. We have $p\mid ab$ but $p$ divides neither $a$ nor $b$.

Answer (score 1):

$4|68=2*34$ but $4 \not \mid 2$ and $4 \not \mid 34$ so this doesn't satisfy that for *ALL* $m,n$ so that $4|mn$ for must divide one or the other.

If $p$ is not prime then $p = nm$ and $n < p; m < p$  so we have $p |p = nm$ but $p \not \mid n$ and $p \not \mid m$ so this fails the condition.  Only primes will pass.